# Modal window on html5 + transition

Tags: html, css, modal-window

I use modal windows on html5 for my menu, but transition doesn't work. Help me find my errors.

```
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
```

[and here is example in online redactor](http://dabblet.com/gist/6080112)

Answer (score 0):

Your `display: none` is hiding the dialog immediately, before the transition starts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the display:none in .modalDialog and set the opacity to 0.

Comment: In this case all page will be not clickable for opera T_T

Comment: just move the modal outside the window before it is active. I.e. you can set top:100% in .modalDialog and then move it to top:0 on .modalDialog:target